# Hadoop uses one node to process data

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a hadoop 2.6.4 setup with 1 master and 2 slaves. All of the nodes appear to be installed properly and can communicate with each other and can ssh to each other without passwords.
I uploaded a 16gb text file to the dfs and ran a simple modified WordCount example ([code here](http://pastebin.com/gxE5eB4q)) on it to test that everything is working.

```
hadoop jar test1.jar WordCount /user/text.txt /user/output
```

I ran my code on the master node and noticed that the master node was doing all of the processing while the slaves were mostly idle. (I monitored the CPU workload)
I then ran the code on slave1 and noticed that the master and slave2 were mostly idle while slave1 did all the work.
Why is the processing done only on the node which the code is submitted on? Is this related to the configuration of hadoop or am I misunderstanding something?

The configuration of the master

core-site

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://master:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
        <value>master:54311</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop_data/hdfs/namenode</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
        <value>master:8025</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
        <value>master:8030</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>master:8050</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

masters:

```
master
```

slaves:

```
slave1
slave2
```

slave1 configuration:

core-site(same as master)

mapred-site(same as master)

hdfs-site

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop_data/hdfs/datanode</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site(same as master)

slaves:

```
 slave1
 slave2
```

Comment: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/

Comment: I have used this link to setup my system, the problem is the job I submit is being processed on the node it is submitted only